# Find longest "binary gap"

Tags: javascript, performance, comparative-review

I'm doing a few challenges and I found this one on Codility:

> A binary gap within a positive integer N is any maximal sequence of
> consecutive zeros that is surrounded by ones at both ends in the
> binary representation of N.
>
> For example, number 9 has binary representation 1001 and contains a
> binary gap of length 2. The number 529 has binary representation
> 1000010001 and contains two binary gaps: one of length 4 and one of
> length 3. The number 20 has binary representation 10100 and contains
> one binary gap of length 1. The number 15 has binary representation
> 1111 and has no binary gaps. The number 32 has binary representation
> 100000 and has no binary gaps.
>
> Write a function:
>
> function solution(N);
>
> that, given a positive integer N, returns the length of its longest
> binary gap. The function should return 0 if N doesn't contain a binary
> gap.
>
> For example, given N = 1041 the function should return 5, because N
> has binary representation 10000010001 and so its longest binary gap is
> of length 5. Given N = 32 the function should return 0, because N has
> binary representation '100000' and thus no binary gaps.
>
> Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:
>
> N is an integer within the range [1..2,147,483,647].

I have 3 solutions (one I found, another I wrote, and the 3rd was based on improvements made to mine)

```
function solution1(N) {
  const binaryString = N.toString(2);
  const start = '10';
  const end = '01';
  let startIndex = binaryString.indexOf(start);
  let endIndex = -1;
  let binaryGap = 0;
  // Remember that N is the
  // input number, and when you iterate over its binary representation, its always
  // log(N).
  while (startIndex >= 0) {
    endIndex = binaryString.indexOf(end, startIndex);
    if (endIndex < 0) {
      break;
    }
    const tempGap = endIndex - startIndex;
    binaryGap = tempGap > binaryGap ? tempGap : binaryGap;
    startIndex = binaryString.indexOf(start, endIndex + 1);
    endIndex = -1;
  }
  return binaryGap;
}
```

```
function solution2(n){
    const results = n.toString(2).split("1").slice(1)
    return results.reduce((acc,next,index)=>(next.length>acc && index<results.length-1  ? next.length : acc) ,0)
}
```

```
const solution3 = (n) => n.toString(2).split("1").slice(1,-1).reduce((acc,next,index)=>(next.length>acc ? next.length : acc) ,0)
```

All seem to be correct (and the solution 2 and 3 passed the test), and the solution 1, according to JSBench is slightly better, but because in the real-world every time we write code we don't test it to see which version is faster, I am curious about which solution is the most elegant and which one would you pick on a real-world scenario (if any one of them fails the challenge you can explain why, but I would love to still hear which one is the best and why, is it because is simpler to maintain/understand, more readable, declarative vs imperative, etc).

Answer (score 1):

All your solutions involve converting the number to a string.  That is more likely to impact performance than any of the other operations you perform.

If you keep the input as a number, you should be able to avoid allocating any new objects, including strings, which will improve your code's performance.